# How to load alternative script file if first script file is not loaded using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, webflow

I am working on a live site hosted on webflow. I have two javascript files

1. http://localhost:3000/dev.js
2. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/live.js

I want to link them in a way if dev.js is not loaded, it will load live.js

I am using the following script, but it keeps pinging dev.js and showing errors in the console. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
<script>
console.log('yes');
$.getScript( "http://localhost:3000/dev.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    //do nothing
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    //load alternative script
    $.getScript( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/live.js" )
      .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        //do nothing
      })
      .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
        console.log( 'Error online script loading' );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What errors does it show?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4zyjLyBp64

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is the error GET http://localhost:3000/esbuild net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929202/connection-refused-on-localhost

Comment: @evolutionxbox no

Comment: Why not? It's the same error you're seeing

Comment: @evolutionxbox it will solve the issue for my local environment yes, but not for other visitors.